# How to open Gtkinspector on Freya?

Tags: release-freya, gtk

I can't see debug under org->gtk->settings or I have to install to get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install the GTK developer tools first.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

Then you will be able to enable the inspector either via the dconf editor, or by executing the terminal command

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
```

You can then launch the Inspector with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

In my experience, the GTK Inspector takes a very long time to load the first time you launch it after launching your GTK app. But after the initial launch, you can close it and it will relaunch much faster.

Comment: This package should be part of the iso image.

Answer (score 1):

The keybinding for Gtk+ Inspector is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

If it is not working, you can enable it with executing this in terminal
`gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true`

Comment: I had mentioned in the question that there is no such setting available `$ gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true`
`No such schema 'org.gtk.Settings.Debug'`

Comment: Should be there in freya. Alternative you could try  to run your program with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive myprogram`

Comment: it too doesn't work

Comment: I am not able to get this working..any inputs?